# troubleshooting about \include

Tags: include

I have probleme with \include as follow

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,epsfig,graphics}


\title{Title}

\author{My name}

\address{Department of Mathematics\\Nice Town} \email{zbigniew@math.org}
\thanks{First author supported in part by
tex.stackexchange}

\begin{document}

\include{abstract}
%\include{introduction}
%\include{chapter1}
%\include{chapter2}
%\include{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

where the absract file is

```
\begin{abstract}
We study some functional inequalities satisfied by differential equations. Such    functional inequalities are obtained through new integration by parts formulas by using the Gronwall lemma.
\end{abstract}
```

in final I have not the abstract.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: In `amsart` the abstract should go before `\maketitle`. Use `\input`, anyway. Don't load `epsfig` and prefer `graphicx` to `graphics`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\maketitle` after `\include{abstract}`.

Comment: should really be `\input{abstract}`.  in this case there seems to be no harm done, but `\include` intentionally starts a new page, which is not ordinarily wanted in an article.