# Texstudio compilation speed

Tags: texstudio

When I compile a 10 page code in texstudio it takes about 1 minute, but when I compile it from the overleaf it takes less time. How can I increase compilation speed in Texstudio.?

Comment: texstudio isn't involved, it is the just the editor, you are running your locally installed tex when you run from texstudio. Basically the speed depends on the speed of your processor and the speed of your filesystem. Overleaf may simply be using a faster  setup.

Comment: So,  Compile only a certain part? Is it possible? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: you could use `\include` to include parts and `\includeonly` to specify individual chapters but for a 10 page document that is unlikely to make any difference, compiling 10 pages will take essentially no time, the time is most likely taken loading documents and packages. But you have given no indication of you setup, for example if your local document is in a folder tracked with dropbox or google drive or similar the overhead in syncing with the remote site can easily take longer than the actual tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My document is on the desktop. I removed it from desktop but compilation takes 40seconds. How to use ```\include```?

Comment: there are literally thousands of examples on this site, eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226439/troubleshooting-about-include

Comment: Thank you sir i understand

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did what you said, but when I compile for a single page, it's still slow

Comment: yes that is what I said, if your document is only 10 pages \include is unlikely to help as any time is probably taken loading files such as packages

Comment: hmm. I understand. How many pages should there be? @DavidCarlisle